Calling SpringBoot Application from a POJO java class
Ok, round 2.  Created dummy projects to show my problem.  Hopefully this makes more sense.
SpringBoot version - 3.3.4 and Java 17.
Project A -
package org.tanuja.testbeds.ProjectA.controller;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.tanuja.testbeds.MCDelegate;


@Controller
public class MCApplication {
    
    @GetMapping("/callpojo")
    public ResponseEntity<String> invokePojo() {
        
        MCDelegate del = new MCDelegate();
        String x = del.sayHello();
        
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(x, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}

MCDelegate is from Project B. Snippet of Pom file for Project A:
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ProjectB</groupId>
        <artifactId>ProjectB</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>Path to jars\lib/ProjectB-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.anjali.testbeds</groupId>
        <artifactId>ProjectC</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>   
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
                <requiresUnpack>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>ProjectC</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ProjectC</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                </requiresUnpack>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

Project B which is JavaProject where I am calling a Service class from ProjectC using simple instantiation



package org.anjali.testbeds;

import org.anjali.testbeds.ProjectC.service.CallService;

public class MCDelegate {
    
    public String sayHello() {      
        CallService service = new CallService();        
        return service.getBooks();      
    }

}

Project C - which is again a SpringBoot application
package org.anjali.testbeds.ProjectC.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class CallService {  
    @Autowired
    TestService service;
    
    public String getBooks(){
        
        List<String> books = service.getBooks();
        return  books.get(0);       
    }

}

package org.anjali.testbeds.ProjectC.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class TestService {
    
    public List<String> getBooks(){
        ArrayList<String> b = new ArrayList<>();
        b.add("Pride&Prejudice");
        b.add("Emma");      
        return b;
    }
}

snippet of Pom file for Project C -
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                 <configuration>
            <classifier>exec</classifier>
            </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

Now the error I am getting.  When I try the rest end point - http://127.0.0.1:8082/callpojo
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Oct 15 14:59:45 EDT 2024
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Cannot invoke "org.anjali.testbeds.ProjectC.service.TestService.getBooks()" because "this.service" is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.anjali.testbeds.ProjectC.service.TestService.getBooks()" because "this.service" is null
    at org.anjali.testbeds.ProjectC.service.CallService.getBooks(CallService.java:17)
    at org.anjali.testbeds.MCDelegate.sayHello(MCDelegate.java:14)
    at org.anjali.testbeds.ProjectA.controller.MCApplication.invokePojo(MCApplication.java:17)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:926)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:831)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:195)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:384)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:905)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Thanks for the help and patience.
I am very new to SpringBoot.  We are trying to convert legacy EJB applications to SpringBoot.
Let's assume I have 3 projects.  Project A is a springboot application, Project B is simple java project and project C is another SringBoot Application.
ProjectA calls Project B and Project B calls Project C.
Project A to B I was able to invoke with no issues.
Project B to C calls, which involves me creating their service class = new ServiceClass().
after fixing the classnotfound exceptions, any autowiring in the Project C is not evaluating they are returning null. It is as if that project is not behaving as SpringBoot project if that makes sense.
Could any one tell me if I am doing this wrong? or is there a specific way to make that call work?
Any help would be much appreciated.
I tried instantiating a class of ProjectC from B and expected it to work.  Class got instantiated but it is not understanding @autowired etc etec..All the spring injected classes are returning null.
